# Centered line code with numbering

Tags: listings, numbering, code

How I can center a line code and numbering it like in the picture?
Is there a command that works inside a lstlisting environment?
Really thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: And what does this number represent? Is it a already existing counter? Is a dedicated counter for listings? Do you need this to have the possibility of cross-referencing?

Comment: Yes it is already existing and I would like to use it for cross-referencing. In the (piece of) document that I posted it is a counter that counts even for equation. For example:

Equation1      (1)  <br/>
Equation 2     (2)  <br/>
LineOfCode   (3)  <br/>
Equation 3     (4)   <br/>
and so on

Comment: is it a single line or part of a longer sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I use my `numberedblock` package, that allows labeled code blocks that can be referenced.  I use brackets instead of parens, so as not to confuse with equation numbering.  With its built-in macros and environments, one can only do code blocks of fixed indent.  However, by employing some additional code, centering can be achieved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numberedblock,lipsum,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\setstackgap{L}{\normalbaselineskip}
              \setlength\maxblocklabelsize{0in}
                     \setlength\blockindent{.2in}
 \renewcommand\blocklabel[1]{\llap{[\textit{\arabic{#1}}]}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
as enthalpy\ldots from the old pressure

\begin{numVblock}[\nbVlabel{cd:a}]
For fixed indent code
Can be verbatim &^%\\
solve(UEqn == - fvc::grad(p));
\end{numVblock}
\setlength\blockindent{0in}

\begin{verbbox}
For centered code
Can be verbatim &^%\\
solve(UEqn == - fvc::grad(p));
\end{verbbox}
\nbVlabel{cd:b}\numblock{\makebox[\textwidth]{\theverbbox}}

In code blocks~\ref{cd:a} and \ref{cd:b}, \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `escapeinside` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,escapeinside=`'}
\newcounter{cnt}
\newcommand\Label[1]{\hfill\refstepcounter{cnt}(\thecnt)\label{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
solve(UEqn == - fvc::grad(p)); `\Label{foo}'
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
solve(UEqn == - fvc::grad(p)); `\Label{bar}'
\end{lstlisting}


also seen in \ref{foo} and \ref{bar} \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You want it centered and using the counter for equations, so the easiest thing would be to use an `equation` and write it inside `\hbox` with the desired format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

some test text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text
\begin{equation}
\hbox{\lstinline!solve(UEqn == - fvc::grad(p));!}
\end{equation}
some test text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems the best option for me, thank you very much Gonzalo

Comment: @DiegoCeglia You're welcome! I updated the answer since just now I read you were using the `listings` package. I show how my answer works using `\lstinline`.

Comment: This is one of the few cases where I'd recommend `\hbox` and not `\text`, if you want to use the full force of `\lstinline` (with category code changes).

Comment: @egreg You are right. I changed accordingly. Thanks.